# "surprised at" vs "surprised by"

Tags: prepositions

> When I saw her fight him, I was surprised **at** how strong she was.
>
> When I saw her fight him, I was surprised **by** how strong she was.

Do both the sentences mean the same thing regardless of which preposition we use in them?

Answer (score 1):

According to Don LePan's "The Broadview Book of Common Errors in English", the grammar rule here is the difference between the two is
1.  Surprised at = the person is disappointed or scandalized whereas
2.  Surprised by = shocked at unexpected outcome.

Comment: There may be some substance to this *in some cases* (in some dialects, at some times, with some people, or whatever). But I think LePan might be overstating this by including it as an "error". It sounds to me like a prescriptivist attempt to draw a distinction where I wouldn't have found one in practice.

Comment: @TimPederick I agree. I often came across both prepositions and in various contexts and basically they both worked in an identical way.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, there is no difference. "Surprised by" is more common, but both will be understood the same way.

Answer (score 0):

1. When I saw her fight him, I was surprised (=adjective) at how strong she was. (Active in meaning, "False Passive" in structure.) [Note: false passive is no passive at all. It's just a theory of a certain school of linguists. As the meaning is active, the voice is active. Just replace "surprised" with "happy" and you will know why.]
2. When I saw her fight him, I was surprised (=past participle) by how strong she was. (Passive voice) [Note: This time you can't replace "surprised" with "happy". I hope you get it.]